# Java stream to get average value based on multiple tables

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-stream

I have 3 related tables; user, movie and score:

***User:**

```
id   | name  |
--------------
1    | Hans  |
2    | Carry |
```

***Movie:**

```
id   | name  | budget |
----------------------
101  | Mov 1 | 200    |
102  | Mov 2 | 500    |
103  | Mov 2 | 300    |
```

***Score:**

```
user_id   | movie_id  | score  |
--------------------------------
1         | 101       | 7      |
2         | 101       | 8      |
1         | 102       | 6      |
2         | 102       | 9      |
```

I am trying to find the 5 movies whose average score is max and then sort these movies based on their budget. So, is that possible using Java Stream? How can I get this kind of list?

Or if it is not possible, should I use Query and retrieve data from projection?

Comment: Sounds like a job for SQL.

Comment: Does anybody else have no idea if this is possible or not using **Java Stream**?

Comment: Stream is possible, but this suit SQL more.
Stream the score list and find all the highest scores and distinct() them by movie_id. then take movie_ids to get a list of movies and sort it the way you want

Comment: Probably, if you can get the data into a stream. You're not giving us any code to work with.

Comment: There's no point in retrieving all this data to your client when it can be processed via SQL on your DB server.

Comment: Thanks a lot to all of you for your useful helps. Then I think I should go on SQL query. Regards...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    record Score(int userId, int movieId, int score) {}
    record Movie(int id, String name, int budget) {}

    List<Movie> movies = List.of(
        new Movie(101, "Mov 1", 200),
        new Movie(102, "Mov 2", 500),
        new Movie(103, "Mov 3", 300));
    List<Score> scores = List.of(
        new Score(1, 101, 6),
        new Score(2, 101, 8),
        new Score(1, 102, 6),
        new Score(2, 102, 9));

    Map<Integer, Movie> movieMap = movies.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Movie::id, Function.identity()));

    List<Movie> top5 = scores.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
            Score::movieId, Collectors.averagingDouble(Score::score)))
        .entrySet().stream()
        .sorted(Collections.reverseOrder(Entry.comparingByValue()))
        .limit(5)
        .map(e -> movieMap.get(e.getKey()))
        .sorted(Collections.reverseOrder(Comparator.comparing(Movie::budget)))
        .toList();
    top5.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

output:

```
Movie[id=102, name=Mov 2, budget=500]
Movie[id=101, name=Mov 1, budget=200]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think, that do by java Stream is not a great idea, because, if ud like to user Pagination, this will not work correctly. (Imagine, that u have 100000000 of movies and scores. Ur server RAM will die)

In ur situation I'll suggest to use JPA query.

```
@Repository
public interface Movie extends JpaRepository<Movie, Long> {
    @Query("select m from Movie m " +
            "left join Score s on s.movie_id == m.id" +
            "order by avg(s.score), m.budget")
    List<Movie> findTopFive();
}
```

I hope, that will help u!

Comment: That should be the common way true - additional information: It still can be a very "expansive" operation so if you're not really 100% having the need that it has the real-time-state i would create a 4th column and run a batchwise calculational scheduler all time long beside. More space but over all less traffic/load on DB and faster available results that are almost "up-to-date"

Comment: Yep. I don't know what DB you use, but I suggest to use Materialised View instead of changing the DB structure. I agree with the rest, but the question is what accuracy is needed. In my projects I use a separate statistics module and database replication for this